# Simple Connection Pooling with psycopg2 and PostgreSQL

Tags: python, postgresql, connection-pool

I am currently using a `SimpleConnectionPool` from `psycopg2` to lease transactions to a PostgreSQL database and would like a review of my current implementation.

#### Code

```py
from contextlib import contextmanager
from dataclasses import dataclass

from psycopg2.pool import SimpleConnectionPool


@dataclass
class PostgreSQLSimplePool:

    pool: SimpleConnectionPool

    @contextmanager
    def transact_session(self, commit: bool = False):
        conn = self.pool.getconn()
        try:
            yield conn
            if commit:
                conn.commit()
        except Exception:
            conn.rollback()
            raise
        finally:
            self.pool.putconn(conn)
```

#### Config

```py
simple_pool = psycopg2.pool.SimpleConnectionPool(
        # testing purposes
        1, 20,
        user=POSTGRES_USER,
        password=POSTGRES_PASS,
        host=POSTGRES_HOST,
        port=POSTGRES_PORT,
        dbname=POSTGRES_DB_NAME,
        sslmode='require'
    )

repo = PostgreSQLSimplePool(pool=simple_pool)
```

#### Usage

```py
with repo.transact_session() as connection:
    with conn.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.RealDictCursor) as cur:
        # do some stuff with the cursor...
```